# Can't install nodejs version using nvm in Mac os

Tags: reactjs, macos, homebrew, nvm

When I try install node version using this command

 `nvm install` or `nvm install 10.6.0`

 I get this output :

```
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:2:1: error: unknown directive
.type _x86_64_AES_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:154:1: error: unknown directive
.size _x86_64_AES_encrypt,.-_x86_64_AES_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:155:1: error: unknown directive
.type _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:6:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:7:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:327:1:        ^
error: unknown directive
.size _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact,.-_x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:329:1: error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:100:8: unknown directive
.type AES_encrypt,@function
error: ^
invalid alignment value
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:332:1: .align 32
       ^
error: unknown directive
.hidden asm_AES_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:394:1: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:207:8: error: error: unknown directive
invalid alignment value
.size AES_encrypt,.-AES_encrypt
.align 32
^
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:395:1: error: unknown directive
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:267:1: .type _x86_64_AES_decrypt,@function
error: ^
unknown directive
.size aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt,.-aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:270:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:271:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:360:8: error: invalid alignment value
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:.align 32
549     : 1 ^: 
error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:467:8: unknown directive
error: .size _x86_64_AES_decrypt,.-_x86_64_AES_decrypt
^
invalid alignment value
.align 32
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:550:1:        ^
error: unknown directive
.type _x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:522:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt,.-aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:523:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt_avx,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:524:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:774:1: error: unknown directive
.size _x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact,.-_x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:776:1: error: unknown directive
.type AES_decrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:779:1: error: unknown directive
.hidden asm_AES_decrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:843:1: error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:671:8: unknown directive
error: .size AES_decrypt,.-AES_decrypt
invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:845:1: error: unknown directive
.type AES_set_encrypt_key,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:958:1: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:864:1: error: error: unknown directive
unknown directive
.size aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt_avx,.-aesni_multi_cbc_encrypt_avx
.size AES_set_encrypt_key,.-AES_set_encrypt_key
^
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:960:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt_avx,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:961:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:1127:8: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:866:1: error: error: unknown directive
.type _x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key,@function
^
invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1104:1: error: unknown directive
.size _x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key,.-_x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1106:1: error: unknown directive
.type AES_set_decrypt_key,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.s:1435:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt_avx,.-aesni_multi_cbc_decrypt_avx
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1291:1: error: unknown directive
.size AES_set_decrypt_key,.-AES_set_decrypt_key
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1293:1: error: unknown directive
.type AES_cbc_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1297:1: error: unknown directive
.hidden asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1748:1: error: unknown directive
.size AES_cbc_encrypt,.-AES_cbc_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:1749:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openss../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:5:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha256_enc,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:33:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha256_enc,.-aesni_cbc_sha256_enc
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:35:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:36:1: error: unknown directive
.type K256,@object
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:76:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:77:1: l/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:error: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_xop,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:78:8: 2139:8: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:5:1: error: error: unknown directive
error: .type aesni_cbc_sha1_enc,@function
invalid alignment value
^
invalid alignment value
.align 64
.align 64
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:6:8:        ^
error:        ^
invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:20:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha1_enc,.-aesni_cbc_sha1_enc
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.s:2534:8: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:21:1: error: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_ssse3,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:22:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:81:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:1374:1: error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:1222:1: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_ssse3,.-aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_ssse3
error: ^
unknown directive
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:1375:1: .size aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_xop,.-aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_xop
^
error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:1223:1: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_avx,@function
error: ^
unknown directive
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:1376:8: .type aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx,@function
^
error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:1224:8: invalid alignment value
.align 32
error:        ^
invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:1433:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:2399:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx,.-aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2672:1: ^
error: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:2400:1: unknown directive
error: .size aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_avx,.-aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_avx
^
unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx2,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2673:8: ../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:2401:error: 8: invalid alignment value
.align 64error: 
       ^
invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2683:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2684:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_shaext,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2685:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.s:2985:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_shaext,.-aesni_cbc_sha1_enc_shaext
^
make[1]: *** [/Users/saidfatah/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.6.0/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha1-x86_64.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [/Users/saidfatah/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.6.0/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-mb-x86_64.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Users/saidfatah/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.6.0/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aes-x86_64.o] Error 1
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:4002:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx2,.-aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_avx2
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:4003:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_shaext,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:4004:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.s:4355:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_shaext,.-aesni_cbc_sha256_enc_shaext
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:4:1: error: make[1]: *** [/Users/saidfatah/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.6.0/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-sha256-x86_64.o] Error 1
unknown directive
.type aesni_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:25:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_encrypt,.-aesni_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:28:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_decrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:49:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_decrypt, .-aesni_decrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:50:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_encrypt2,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:78:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_encrypt2,.-_aesni_encrypt2
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:79:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_decrypt2,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:107:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_decrypt2,.-_aesni_decrypt2
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:108:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_encrypt3,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:141:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_encrypt3,.-_aesni_encrypt3
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:142:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_decrypt3,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:175:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_decrypt3,.-_aesni_decrypt3
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:176:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_encrypt4,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:215:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_encrypt4,.-_aesni_encrypt4
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:216:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_decrypt4,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:255:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_decrypt4,.-_aesni_decrypt4
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:256:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_encrypt6,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:309:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_encrypt6,.-_aesni_encrypt6
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:310:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_decrypt6,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:363:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_decrypt6,.-_aesni_decrypt6
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:364:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_encrypt8,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:427:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_encrypt8,.-_aesni_encrypt8
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:428:1: error: unknown directive
.type _aesni_decrypt8,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:491:1: error: unknown directive
.size _aesni_decrypt8,.-_aesni_decrypt8
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:493:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ecb_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:833:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ecb_encrypt,.-aesni_ecb_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:835:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ccm64_encrypt_blocks,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:896:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ccm64_encrypt_blocks,.-aesni_ccm64_encrypt_blocks
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:898:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ccm64_decrypt_blocks,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:993:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ccm64_decrypt_blocks,.-aesni_ccm64_decrypt_blocks
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:995:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1194:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1479:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1508:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1566:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,.-aesni_ctr32_encrypt_blocks
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1568:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_xts_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1654:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:1702:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2031:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_xts_encrypt,.-aesni_xts_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2033:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_xts_decrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2125:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2173:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2533:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_xts_decrypt,.-aesni_xts_decrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2535:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ocb_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2536:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2600:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2726:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ocb_encrypt,.-aesni_ocb_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2728:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_encrypt6,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2729:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2790:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2828:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_encrypt6,.-__ocb_encrypt6
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2830:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_encrypt4,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2831:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2869:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2897:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_encrypt4,.-__ocb_encrypt4
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2899:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_encrypt1,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2900:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2916:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2932:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_encrypt1,.-__ocb_encrypt1
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2935:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_ocb_decrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:2936:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3001:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3148:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_ocb_decrypt,.-aesni_ocb_decrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3150:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_decrypt6,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3151:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3206:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3244:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_decrypt6,.-__ocb_decrypt6
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3246:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_decrypt4,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3247:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3281:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3309:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_decrypt4,.-__ocb_decrypt4
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3311:1: error: unknown directive
.type __ocb_decrypt1,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3312:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3327:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 32
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3343:1: error: unknown directive
.size __ocb_decrypt1,.-__ocb_decrypt1
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3345:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_cbc_encrypt,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3928:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_cbc_encrypt,.-aesni_cbc_encrypt
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3930:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_set_decrypt_key,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3968:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_set_decrypt_key,.-aesni_set_decrypt_key
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:3970:1: error: unknown directive
.type aesni_set_encrypt_key,@function
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:4338:1: error: unknown directive
.size aesni_set_encrypt_key,.-aesni_set_encrypt_key
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:4339:1: error: unknown directive
.size __aesni_set_encrypt_key,.-__aesni_set_encrypt_key
^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:4340:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
../deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s:4361:8: error: invalid alignment value
.align 64
       ^
make[1]: *** [/Users/saidfatah/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.6.0/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/config/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.o] Error 1
rm a57cc39f9a4926a7c89e2f46f447db84f350c302.intermediate
make: *** [node] Error 2
nvm: install v10.6.0 failed!
```

*Note I installed nvm using `Brew install nvm`

Comment: I get the same errors on my new macbook pro with the Apple Silicon chip.
Trying to run the command `nvm install 10`

Comment: I should actually answer my own question I managed to get this done by witching to the old terminal architecture

Comment: @LucasCazeto you could add this before your command ```arch -x86_64```

Comment: I also managed to make it work by running in "rosetta" mode. I guess they do the same thing!

Comment: @LucasCazeto yes I guess so

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case if you want to run rosetta apps multiple times in your current shell, you can prepend the following line:

```sh
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
# ...
nvm install 10
# Do all the x86_64 commands you want including building stuff using node-gpy
```

This will enter a "rosetta mode" in terminal from which you can quit just by typing `exit` in terminal

---

You can create an alias for that. By running the following command you will add alias `x86` which will log into your rosette terminal once you type it

```sh
echo 'alias x86="env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thank you! When I run `arch -x86_64 nvm install 10`, it says it cannot find nvm in PATH. However, your version works well. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems that `arch` command does not search local PATHs (located in user zsh config). There is a good chance that you have added nvm path to user defined zsh config. Check out `~/.zshrc`. The command I provided above initialises a new zsh session for your current user - this way it also reads your local .zshrc config file and exported nvm paths inside of it.

Comment: @PhoenixHimself sorry, what does that mean? I have in the file:
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

-> Should I change something? Without it, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

the solution for me was to prefix each command by `arch -x86_64`
so in my case it was `arch -x86_64 nvm install 10.6.0` 

 some people also suggest opening terminal in `rosetta` mode

Answer (score 0):

1. [enable Rosetta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W8rTTE1WEA) on Terminal using Right Click
2. input following on terminal: - `arch`
3. output should be i386
4. quit terminal using `command+q` and then reopen terminal
5. `nvm install 10.6.0`